# Why getLocalPricing() and getLocalName() return null

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play

I want to implement google play subscriptions via gdx-pay library. To display the information I need, I ask

```java
info = purchaseManager.getInformation(SKU);
info.getLocalName(); //returns null
info.getLocalPricing(); //returns null
```

But these methods return `null`
Here is my code

```java
PurchaseManagerConfig pmc = new PurchaseManagerConfig();
pmc.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.SUBSCRIPTION).setIdentifier(SKU));
//pmc.addStoreParam(PurchaseManagerConfig.STORE_NAME_ANDROID_GOOGLE, param);
purchaseManager.install(new MyObserver(this), pmc, true);
...
info = purchaseManager.getInformation(SKU);
```

I looked at the documentation and an example for this library, but did not find any problems, the only thing I did not write `pmc.addStoreParam(PurchaseManagerConfig.STORE_NAME_ANDROID_GOOGLE, param);` Because I don't understand what parameters are needed there. In addition, this line is not used in the example, so I skipped it. I have not yet had time to write a subscription purchase implementation. I created a subscription, registered a price for it, added an ID and activated. In the developer console, I have not seen any notes about a possible delay after creating a subscription. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say what exactly helped, but the problem went away (at least during the testing phase). A few days later, I changed a few things: I published the game to the public, started working on a new version, created another OAuth 2.0 client ID with SHA-1 upload certificate, added it to the firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

From the readme file on gdx-pay:

> When the PurchaseManager is sucessfully installed, your PurchaseObserver will receive a callback and purchaseManager.installed() will return true. That might take some seconds depending on the payment service. You can now request information or purchase items.

We don't know if you do this, probably you don't and you just get Information.UNAVAILABLE returned.

Comment: I have checked `purchaseManager.installed()`. Now I'll try to check `Information.UNAVAILABLE`

Comment: I get `Information.UNAVAILABLE` all the time no matter how much time has passed. With that, `purchaseManager.installed()` returns true

Comment: Then you are probably using a nonexisting SKU

Comment: Is this the only possible reason? I googled to see if I got sku in the right place. It turned out that in the right place - on the page with subscriptions, the product identifier. There are no typos, the identifier is exactly the same as in the console.